# How to launch app in iOS 17 device using Flutter 3.0.5

Tags: ios, flutter

Is there a workaround to launch flutter app on iOS 17 without upgrading flutter to 3.13?

XCode version is 15.2

The issue is https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133465

It was fixed in Flutter 3.13+

I know best would be to update flutter, just wondering if there is a way to avoid it for now because it may take weeks of work.

Comment: Is your XCode on the latest version, if yes and it supports the device you should be fine, what issue are you facing, I think you need to elaborate on your issue a little here

Comment: Could you added what errors are you facing?, but it'll be better if you can update your app instead of making workarounds